# django values function strange behaviors?

Tags: python, django

I have +5 hours training to explain how : `Item.objects.values('type', 'state')` returns a dictionary that contains only two keys.

However `Item.objects.values('type', 'state').annotate(nb=Count('id'))` works !!

How does the interpreter knows that `id` attribute exists if it's not returned by values function ?

Comment: If you don't specify the 'id' field, I don't see any problem, it returns only the fields you've specified unless you omit the fields parameters.Take a look at `ValuesIterable` class in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py and check the last example in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values. About your last question, it seems like you're trying to use `values` to a different purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It knows that the `id` attribute exists because `Item.objects.values('type', 'state')` isn't just a dictionary. It's a object that *represents* itself as a dictionary based on the parameters you give it.

Imagine the object is a piece of paper, let's call it paper `A`:

```
id : 1
type : cheese
state : melted
```

What you're actually seeing when you call it is a representation of that object created by only showing you the relevant parts, like a piece of paper with holes put on top of `A`, paper `B`:

```
████████████████████
████████████████████
+--------------------+
|type: cheese        |
+--------------------+
+--------------------+
|state: melted       |
+--------------------+
```

But paper `A` is still underneath paper `B`, intact. That's why `Item.objects.values('type', 'state').annotate(nb=Count('id'))` works: when `annotate` goes to look at the object, it's asking for what it actually *is*, not what it looks like to an outside observer. In other words, `annotate` looks at paper `A`, *not* paper `B`.

By having the object `Item.objects.values('type', 'state')` represent itself differently to the user and the system, it allows the system to retain as much information as possible in case it needs to check it. This is common in ORM models so that discrepancies don't arise between the database and representations of the database.

Comment: type(Item.objects.values('type', 'state')) gives the answer I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your model has id in background and also Django ORM is aware of your model definition

Django ORM is **lazy loading** and it wont execute nothing before result is called. So in moment when you are calling annotate it is not yet a dictionary it is still object. In moment that you ask for it result it triggers query to database and returns your result

Django ORM translates this into query to the database similar to this

```
SELECT type, state, count(id) as nb FROM items
```

Comment: My question is simple. how can annotate knows of 'id' existance if it's called from a dictionary that doesn't have it

Comment: @user2080105 your model has id in background and also Django ORM is aware of your model definition

Comment: Django ORM is lazy loading and it wont execute nothing before result is called. So in moment when you are calling annotate it is not yet a dictionary it is still ORM object

Answer (score 0):

The first query does *not* return a dictionary with two keys. On the contrary, it returns a ValuesQuerySet; each element of that queryset is a dictionary.

The ValuesQuerySet, like any other queryset, retains a connection with the model, and it is therefore able to add any other elements to the query as necessary. The query as a whole is not executed until the queryset is iterated.